# upload image to node js server + javascript and display in the same page with ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I need to upload a image(jpg||png||jpeg) to the server I created with node js.

I have the router and the requestHandlers.. that redirect to this function:

```
  function reqUpload(request, response) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(request, function (error, fields, files) {
        lastFileUploaded=files.up.originalFilename;
        if (files.up.originalFilename.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i)) {
            //check if alredy exists
            fs.access(files.up.originalFilename, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    fs.rename(files.up.filepath, files.up.originalFilename, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            fs.unlink(files.up.originalFilename);
                            fs.rename(files.up.filepath, files.up.originalFilename);
                        }

                        var data;
                        fs.readFile('./html/std.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                                return
                            }
                            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
                            response.write(data);
                            response.end();
                            
                        });
                    })
                }else{
                    console.log("Already exists, replacing it!");
                    fs.rename(files.up.filepath, files.up.originalFilename, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            fs.unlink(files.up.originalFilename);
                            fs.rename(files.up.filepath, files.up.originalFilename);
                        }
                })}

            });
        } else {
            console.log("format not accepted! try again.");

        }
```

> This is working if I upload my file via a button and the form action ="/reqUpload"
> however, I need to load in the same page.

How do I do it with ajax + jquery?

I need to display the image uploaded in the same page I uploaded it, without refreshing the page.

I have this function:

```
function loadPhoto(e){

alert("entered")   
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/reqUpload');
xhr.onload = function(){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    alert(this.responseText)
         document.getElementById('#photo').innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
xhr.send('/html/std.html');
e.preventDefault();
```

}

> but it breaks and returns this:
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nKzQ.png)

seems not to send the file in the correct format, or smth like that

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my case

```
function loadPhoto(e){
e.preventDefault();
//forming images
var formData  = new FormData( document.getElementById("uploading") );
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("up").files.length; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  formData.append("up[]",document.getElementById("up").files[i]);
}


var filename = document.getElementById('up');
alert(filename)
filename = filename.files[0].name;
alert(filename)

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/reqUpload');
xhr.onload = function(){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    alert(this.responseText)
         document.getElementById('#photo').innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
xhr.send(formData);
```

}